# Microsoft issues free exam vouchers on Office 365 (and Azure)

Tags: discussion

Until the end of this year, you can certify yourself for free to both Office 365 certifications within the MCP program. List yourself on the [**free voucher page**](https://vouchers.cloudapp.net/mcp/default.aspx). Please note that these exams from now on are a part of the MCSE SharePoint and has replaced the three previous Windows Server certifications (70-410, 70-411, 70-412).

- [Exam 70-346 Managing Office 365 Identities and Requirements](https://www.microsoft.com/learning/en-us/exam-70-346.aspx)
- [Exam 70-347 Enabling Office 365 Services](https://www.microsoft.com/learning/en-us/exam-70-347.aspx)

## [MCSE: SharePoint](https://www.microsoft.com/learning/en-us/mcse-sharepoint-certification.aspx)

[image]

> Terms and Conditions for Microsoft Certification Vouchers:
>
> - Limit five (5) exam vouchers per individual
> - Offer good until December 31, 2014 for up to a total of 10,000 vouchers distributed worldwide.
> - Eligible exams: A voucher may be redeemed to take one of the following MCP exams: 71-532 (beta), 70-533, 70-346 or 70-347. This offer does not include Microsoft Technology Associate exams.
> - Offer ends on December 31, 2014 or while supplies last. Individuals must register for and take all exams prior to December 31, 2014.
> - Vouchers may not be used for any other offering than the specified offer.
> - Microsoft, Prometric and APTCs are not responsible for lost or stolen vouchers or voucher numbers.
> - Vouchers may not be redeemed for cash, credit or refunds.
> - Expired, stolen or lost vouchers will not be replaced.
> - Vouchers may not be applied to exams that have already been taken.
> - Vouchers are nontransferable and are void if altered or revised in any way.
> - Any resale or distribution of vouchers is expressly prohibited.
> - Taxes, if any, are the sole responsibility of the recipient.
> - There is a rescheduling fee for individuals who reschedule or cancel their appointment to take an exam 15 or fewer days before the scheduled date.
> - Individuals that cancel or reschedule their appointment to take an exam seventy-two hours or less from the scheduled time will forfeit their exam voucher (voucher cannot be used again).
> - Individuals that fail to show up for their scheduled exam appointment will forfeit their exam voucher (voucher cannot be used again).
> - Voucher expiration dates cannot be extended under any circumstances.
> - To register for an exam, visit the Prometric website www.prometric.com. You must provide the Voucher code provided by Prometric when registering to take an exam.
> - Exam 71-532 is a beta exam and all beta policies apply.
> - Due to government gift and ethics laws, government employees (including military and employees of public education institutions) are not eligible to participate.

Answer (score 1):

The offer is now closed:

> Thank you for your interest. This offer is now closed for further
>   voucher requests. If you have already received a voucher, be sure to
>   schedule and take your exam by December 31, 2014. Good luck!

Thank you for the heads up, Benny, I managed to beat the crowd and get my vouchers earlier thanks to you.

Comment: Great! I'll  remove the Feature-tag, which will remove the post from the landing page.